# cant make array to function

Tags: php, arrays, function

first sorry for my english
I have array will used by function

1. Upload text file and every line will be element in array

   ```
   $fh = fopen("upload/".'1.txt','r');
   $conn = array();
   while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
       $conn[] = $line;
   }
   fclose($fh);
   $wbs->SendBulk($conn, "hello world");
   ```
2. Go To Function

   ```
   public function SendBulk($targets, $message)
   {
       echo "Sending " . count($targets) . " bulk messages...<br />";

       foreach($targets as $target)
       {
           $this->wa->sendPresenceSubscription($target);
           $this->wa->pollMessages();
           $this->wa->sendMessageComposing($target);
           sleep(55);
           $this->wa->pollMessages();
           $this->wa->sendMessagePaused($target);
           static::$sendLock = true;
           echo "Sending message from " . $this->username . " to $target... ";
           $this->wa->sendMessage($target, $message); // Orginal
           while(static::$sendLock)
           {
               //wait for server receipt
               sleep(55);
           }
       }
   ```

My Problem If I have in text file 2 or more element in array 
will send for the last element a message 
but If i make array like this

```
$conn= array("565684898", "484849815", "484897987", "515498798");
```

It work for all elements
Please Help

Comment: Sorry to say it's really difficult to comprehend what you're trying to convey here, at least for me

Comment: What does your `$conn` array have anything to do with the `SendBulk` function?

Comment: I really don't understand. All I can tell you for now is that if you want to build an array from a file where each line is an array element, you can use the PHP function file() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. But I don't know if you want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string returned by `fgets()` includes the newline that ends each line. Use `rtrim()` to remove it:

```
$conn[] = rtrim($line);
```

You can also replace your entire code that reads the file with:

```
$conn = file('upload/1.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
```